# Scanner and user's inputs

Tags: java

Using the code below, the loop does not end when I use +, - and Q.

```
String[] validOperators = {"+", "-", "/", "*", "=", "q", "Q"};
String userInput; 
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter an operation (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): ");
userInput = scanner.nextLine();

while(Arrays.binarySearch(validOperators, userInput) <= -1) {
    System.out.print("Invalid input (+, -, /, *, = or Q to quit): ");
    userInput = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Why this happens and how can I implemented with the right way?

Comment: `Arrays.binarySearch` requires a sorted array, sort the array before you're searching with `Arrays.sort(validOperators)`

Comment: If you want to make sure that user provided correct value from some predefined collection use sets and its `contains` method.

Comment: @Pshemo I did not think the set with contains method. This is very good alternative, I have experience in Python.

Comment: @wiomoc it works thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), available since Java 8. For example :

```
Arrays.stream(validOperators).anyMatch(userInput::equals)
```

If you need a better performance solution for a small list of elements, both memory and process efficient and that doesn't use syntactic sugar or Java 8 streams (while loop is clearer and improved thanks to [Vinod Singh Bist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7234630/vinod-singh-bist)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] validOperators = {'+', '-', '/', '*', '=', 'q', 'Q'}; // String is more expensive
    char userInput;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid operation ( +, -, /, *, = , q or Q ) to quit: ");
        userInput = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    }while(!contains(validOperators, userInput)) ;
}

private static boolean contains(char[] elements, char c) {
    // for loop is usually faster for small lists than any built-in iterator for primitives like char
    for (int i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (elements[i] == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Idea behind OP code is to improve performance with binary-search. This doesn't seem to offer it.

Comment: didn't notice it was for performance issues. If so, I think the solution should be completly refactored. Do you think it's about performance on a search over a 7 elements array?

Comment: 7 elements could be only an example, but I can be wrong. Anyway IMO people don't use binary-search just to make their code look better but for potential performance gain so I would say that is main purpose of OP code. But if there are really only 7 options then your solution wouldn't probably be much slower than what OP has and in some cases it could be even faster.

Comment: @Pshemo for the records they are only 7 elements but I keep in mind that it is fast technique for searching. Thanks.

Comment: @FranciscoTena +1 for your answer. Although, the syntax is cryptographic for me right now.

Comment: The syntax is weird at the beginning because since Java8 the language evolved into something more functional with lots of classes with predicates and streams but you'll get used to it quickly and you'll notice that it's easier to read and most of the times better even in performance.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.binarySearch(validOperators, userInput)` require sorted array.

If array is not `sorted`, the results are `undefined`. You should you `Arrays.sort(validOperators);`

Answer (score 1):

Try below mentioned solution.

```
    String[] validOperators = {"+", "-", "/", "*", "=", "q", "Q"};
    String userInput; 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Arrays.sort(validOperators);

    do{
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid operation ( +, -, /, *, = , q or Q ) to quit: ");
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    }while(Arrays.binarySearch(validOperators, userInput) <= -1);
```

Comment: I like your do-while loop approach